# Access Parse Object ID right after instantiation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm creating two `PFObject`s at the same time that should reference each other's object IDs when they're saved. In the example below, the second object is supposed to save the first object's object ID in an array.

```
let objectForFirstClass = PFObject(className:"ClassOne")
let objectForSecondClass = PFObject(className: "ClassTwo")
objectForSecondClass.setObject([objectForFirstClass.objectId!], forKey: "classOneObjectArray")
```

The last line is causing the error because `objectForFirstClass.objectId` is nil. I'd assume this is because the object hasn't been saved yet. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save after creating the first object, and in the completion handler, create the second one with a reference to the first one.

You can use [`saveAllInBackground:block:`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(cm)saveAllInBackground:block:) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the object id is assigned by the server when saved. I'd be tempted to write some cloud code to do what you want so you can send some details and the cloud code will create and connect the objects, then return both of them to you. You can of course do the same thing locally in your app, there's just more network comms.

You should also consider using pointers or relationships. These are better for querying, though the same save requirements apply before you can set the connections.